# Adding two sine waves using euler

Tags: trigonometry, wave-equation

I have two sinusoidal functions: x1(t)=sin(30t) and x2(t)=0.7sin(30t + 9)

Now I want to get y(t)=x1(t) + x2(t)

I want to get y(t) as a sinusoidal function.

I'm supposed to solve this using Euler's Formula but I can't seem to solve it. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've tried so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jog4j.jpg

(Please excuse the shameful handwriting)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please show us what you have tried so far 
and where you are stuck, i.e edit your post with this information. This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Show us your application of Euler's formula, or its equivalent $sin(30t)=Im(e^{i30t}), \cdots$ and where you are stuck.

Comment: @JeanMarie Done, thank you for the heads up!

Comment: @JKnecht Done, thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work by assuming that the given signals are the imaginary parts of complex exponentials, and compute

$$e^{i30t}+0.7e^{i(30t+9)}=(1+0.7e^{i9})e^{i30t}.$$

The constant factor is, in polar form,

$$1+0.7e^{i9}=1+0.7\cos(9)+i0.7\sin(9)=\sqrt{(1+0.7\cos(9))^2+(0.7\sin(9))^2}e^{i\arctan(0.7\sin(9)/(1+0.7\cos(9)))},$$

and

$$(1+0.7e^{i9})e^{i30t}=\sqrt{(1+0.7\cos(9))^2+(0.7\sin(9))^2}e^{i(30t+\arctan(0.7\sin(9)/(1+0.7\cos(9))))},$$

giving

$$y(t)=\sqrt{(1+0.7\cos(9))^2+(0.7\sin(9))^2}\sin(30t+\arctan(0.7\sin(9)/(1+0.7\cos(9)))).$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed yet simple answer, this method is much easier than the one I used.

Comment: @tsuoeuoy: this is a classical method, which works for an arbitrary number of sinusoids (of equal pulsation): you convert the polar forms (amplitude, phase) to Cartesian, sum, and convert back.